# Inject dateFilter in a service in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I would like to know if there is a way to inject the filters in a service in AngularJs.

I've been trying

```
app.factory('educationService', [function($rootScope, $filter) {

    // ..... Some code

    // What I want
    console.log(dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-01'));

    // ..... Some code

}]);
```

So I would like to know if it is possible to inject a filter in a service or maybe it is accessible in another way.

And if you have a link to a documentation about this point, it would be really nice :) Been searching in the doc of Angular and I found nothing really helpful about this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First you have to inject the filter like this:

```
app.factory('myService', ['$rootScope', '$filter', function($rootScope, $filter)
```

(The array is only needed when you use minification in your build process)

To call specific filter programmatically:

```
$filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-01');
```

`$filter(name)`returns the specific filter function, which you can than call with your arguments:

```
var dateFilter = $filter('date');
var filteredDate = dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-01')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I tried it when I was searching but I had an error "$filter is not a function" so I thought this was wrong. I am going to check what's going on. Maybe a missing dependence or something like that.

Is the way to pass $filter in my example good?

Comment: Not good enough if you're minifying your scripts. You'll always be safe with `app.factory('educationService', ['$rootScope', '$filter', function($rootScope, $filter) {...`. It seems that you used the inline annotation but you forgot to safe-inject the actual dependencies inside the array.

Comment: Yes I minify my scripts. Thanks for the info it works perfectly now :)

Comment: Thanks!  The AngularJS documentation appears to be incorrect.  They show the following: $filter('date', object)

Answer (score 46):

> The filter function is registered with the `$injector` under the filter name suffixed with `Filter`.  -- [$filterProvider docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24filterProvider)

This is true for the Angular built-in filters, as well as your own custom filters.

So, you can inject the `dateFilter` into your service like this (if not minifying):

```
app.factory('educationService', [function($rootScope, dateFilter) {
```

If you are only using one filter, this method allows you to be more specific about your actual dependencies.  If you need to use multiple filters, you can inject `$filter` like @Stewie shows.

Comment: +1 This answer is more correct than the selected answer from @Stewie because this one mentions the ability to inject a specific filter instead of the entire `$filter` service

Comment: +1 I kept doing `filterDate` instead of `dateFilter`. This was what I was looking for, I knew there had to be a better way than injecting the entire `$filter` service.