# how to use angularjs (filter service) without html (for chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I try to use filter angularjs service in my chrome extension. But i have no idea how to get/inject it in my function.
For the moment i have:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    result = $filter('filter')(jsonArray, info.selectionText, function (actual, expected) {
        return actual.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) == 0;
    });
    console.log(sug);
});
```

But obviously i have: $filter is not defined.
I also want to use $http service to get my jsonArray

Comment: Inject dependencies in the controller/provider/module in which the function is

Comment: i have no controller/provider/module. I just want to use filter alone.

Comment: You don't need all of angular just to filter an array. It's built in since ES5, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ok! But i also use $http to get my json array.. So in general how to use angularjs service without controller/provider/module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
var myInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
var $filter = myInjector.get("$filter");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

where-ever you are using $filter, you need to add the dependency for the same. you can add the dependency by providing a $filter as a parameter to main function.

**if adding inside controller :**

```
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
      $scope.originalText = 'hello';
      $scope.filteredText = $filter('uppercase')($scope.originalText);
});
```

**if adding inside factory/service :**

```
app.factory('myService', ['$filter', function($filter)
```

this link may help you for more information :
[Inject dateFilter in a service in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408336/inject-datefilter-in-a-service-in-angularjs)

Comment: Ok but how to use myService without controller ?

Comment: I think this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319784/call-angularjs-service-from-simple-js-code